# CC3200 Firmware - gaining information about - Registers / Memory (Ghidra) - SVD / CMSIS

Tags: ghidra

I am currently reversing a firmware for the TI CC3200 (ARM Cortex M4) via ghidra.

For other ARM chips I have learned that I may use a SVD-Loader to load all information about the registers and memory into ghidra. As it seems there are no SVD files available to import the information automatically.
Also adding the ROM functions provided by the driverlib would significantly help.

Are there different ways to load that information into ghidra (without doing it manually using the tech reference). What kind of files I could extract that information from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the header files from the sample code/SDK provided by the manufacturer. Often they have regular structure and can be parsed with a bit of scripting.